# Unable to delete records with the correct command

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, sql-delete

I am unable to delete these records. How to get around the foreign key?

My tables:

users table:

[image: users table]

user_locations table:

[image: user_locations table]

Command and Error:

[image: Command and Error]

Comment: 'How to get around the foreign key?' - get round?

Comment: You are trying to violate referential integrity, that's why the system forbids you from doing so.

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key constraint prevents your from deleting a parent record as long as it is referenced by any child record. This corresponds to the default referential action, that is `on delete restrict`.

There are, however, other options available. Unless you have good reasons not to, I would recommend changing the referential to `on delete cascade`: so children records are automatically dropped when the parent goes away.

This requires recreating the constraint:

```
alter table user_locations drop foreign key user_locations_user_id_foreign;  

alter table user_locations 
    add constraint user_locations_user_id_foreign
    foreign key (user_id) references users (id) on delete cascade;
```

With this set up in place, you can just run your original `delete` statement; children records will be automatically deleted at the same time as the parent record(s).